# Multiple interfaces to same concrete class

Tags: polymorphism, ninject

Shouldn't this just work?

Interface

```
public interface IConfig : ISmtpConfig, IEventConfig
```

Binding

```
kernel.Bind<IConfig>().To<Config>();
```

Usage

```
public SmtpClient(ISmtpConfig config)
```

It complaints that it cant find any bindings for ISmtpConfig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from anders is correct. This answer here follows up the comments from steven and anders. If you use the conventions extension there is a `BindAllInterfaces()`. This automagically binds all interfaces of the class. Here is an example:

```
kernel.Bind( x => x
    .FromThisAssembly() // 1
    .SelectAllClasses().InNamespaceOf<IConfig>() // 2
    .BindAllInterfaces() // 3
    .Configure(b => b.InSingletonScope())); // 4
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll keep this question here because if you google 'Concrete' google wont link to SO.
You need to do

```
kernel.Bind<IConfig, IEventConfig, ISmtpConfig>()
```

To me this is redundant information, but maybe its hard to do it dynamically

Comment: Ninject (and any other container I know of) force you to explicitly define the interface/service of a component you are registering. This interface is used as key to be able to lookup that type. It could lead to all sorts of subtle errors, since just adding an interface to class or interface would immediately make it resolvable, which might not always be what you want. So it is not hard to find this out dynamically, but Ninject is saving your ass here ;-)

Comment: True, but you could have a special Binding for these kind of scenarios to avoid those problems. kernel.Bind<>().WithAncestors() or something